# Django syntax error after activated venv and checking python and django version

Tags: python, django, api, server

I've already activated my venv FYP2, and also check my python and django version, they are all compatible, I have no idea why this error keeps coming up.

Python = 2.7.16
Django = 1.11

```
(base) C:\Users\Gary>cd FYP2

(base) C:\Users\Gary\FYP2>activate FYP2

(FYP2) C:\Users\Gary\FYP2>python manage.py runserver
  File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

(FYP2) C:\Users\Gary\FYP2>python --version
Python 2.7.16 :: Anaconda, Inc.

(FYP2) C:\Users\Gary\FYP2>python -m django --version
1.11

(FYP2) C:\Users\Gary\FYP2>
```

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "api.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Please post your `manage.py`. It looks like it uses Python3 syntax (hence, it was generated with Django 2.0 or higher)

Comment: Just updated the post.

Comment: Are you sure that particular project is supposed to be run with that Django version on Python 2…‽

Comment: I'm not sure, I've used python 3.7 before this, but some of the package is not compatible to python 3.7, should I just update it back?